# MVT Find bound A and B

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

My friend threw this problem a few days ago, I don't recall the MVT ... could someone help me?

Suppose that  $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}$  and  $f(0)=2$.

What bounds A and B, $A<f(4)<B$ come directly from the **MVT**?

(Answers should be written as fractions)

PD: I know I have been posting a lot of stuff, these questions have been sitting on my desk some months know and I am just excited to use this platform

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can exactly get $f(4)$ without MVT here.

$f(x)=12x+\frac{x^2}{2}+c$ and since $f(0)=2$ then $c=2$

Thus $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+12x+2$, so $f(4)=58$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Fareed. Smart move, I did that as well. Nevertheless, it is the value of **A** and **B** that have to be found

Comment: I think you mean $f(x) = 12 + \tfrac12 x^2 + c$.

Answer (score 0):

By the Mean Value Theorem,
$$
    f(4) = f(0) + f'(t)\cdot 4
$$
where $t$ is some number in the open interval $(0,4)$.  Since $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2+x}$, we know that for all $t\in (0,4)$,
$$
    \frac{1}{6} < f'(t) < \frac{1}{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
   2 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 4 < f(4)  < 2 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 4 
\implies \frac{8}{3} < f(4) < 4
$$

---

I kind of agree with Fareed; the MVT is not the right tool for this job since $f(x)$ can be found directly from $f'(x)$.  But this is the technique used to estimate $f(x)$ when you know information about (e.g., upper and lower bounds of)  $f'(x)$.

Comment: I realized a typo, it should be $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}$ not $f'(x)=12+x$ ...My mistake!

Comment: Ah, well, it’s still monotonic so the bounds are on the endpoints. I’ll fix it soon.

Comment: @mephistopheles see edits